# How to express a polar coordinate for a macro that only accepts space-separated values?

Tags: pstricks

`\psElectricfield` only accepts a coordinate in space-separated values as follows. For example, a charge of -0.1 unit at (-1,0) is written as `[-0.1 -1 0]`. I have attempted to write in PS notation but it still does not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{pst-electricfield,multido}
\def\M{2}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+30}{12}{%
\begin{pspicture*}(-\M,-\M)(\M,\M)
    \psElectricfield
    [
        Q={[-0.1 -1 0][-0.1 1 0][0.1 !\i sin 2 mul \i cos 2 mul]}
    ]
\end{pspicture*}\newpage}
\end{document}
```

How to express  a polar coordinate for a macro that only accepts space-separated values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}\parindent=0pt    
\usepackage{pst-electricfield,multido}
\def\M{2}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+30}{12}{%
\begin{pspicture*}(-\M,-\M)(\M,\M)
    \psElectricfield[Q={
       [-0.1 -1 0]
       [-0.1 1 0]
       [0.1 \i\space sin 2 mul 
            \i\space cos 2 mul]}]
\end{pspicture*} }
\end{document}
```

you have to use `{\i}` or alternatively `\i\space` otherwise the following  space gets lost and you'll get a wrong PostScript entry like `10sin` where the space is missing ("eaten" by TeX)

[image]

Comment: +1 Why do we not need `!` for PS notation?

Comment: there is only PS code possible, nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Based on Herbert's solution, I added `\pstVerb` to it such that the code can be broken into several lines that are often needed when they are posted to a narrow HTML page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}\parindent=0pt    
\usepackage{pst-electricfield,multido}
\def\M{2}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+30}{12}{%
\begin{pspicture*}[showgrid](-\M,-\M)(\M,\M)
    \pstVerb{/xx \i\space sin 2 mul def}%
    \pstVerb{/yy \i\space cos 2 mul def}%   
    \psElectricfield
    [
        Q={[-0.1 -1 0][-0.1 1 0][0.1 xx yy]}
    ]
\end{pspicture*} }
\end{document}
```

Comment: or: how can one make things complecated instead of easy ...